# Missing properties in properties window

Tags: modifiers, properties

[image]

Hi guys, I don't know how it happened, it might be some shortcut that I don't know about. Everything is okay when I open up a new project but when I load my previous file it looks like that.

Also, I have a problem with modifiers.

[image]

---

It just disappeared after deselecting the object. My bad. But modifiers still won't work and there's a few of them.

[image]

Comment: The Curve Modifier is Red because you have not entered a valid curve into the Object box. If you click into the Object box and nothing shows in the drop down then there are no eligible curves in your scene.

Answer (score 1):

Most tabs in the properties panel are only displayed if the active object is a certain type. If there is no active object, most of them will be hidden, as you have discovered. It's a bit uncommon to have no active object, but it is possible; deleting all objects in the scene, or creating a new empty scene are two ways. It's also possible to set it in python (`bpy.context.scene.objects.active = None`), and indeed some addons will (intentionally or otherwise) introduce such a state.

Similarly, not all modifiers can be applied to curve objects. Hence, not all modifiers are available in the drop down while a curve object is selected.